# WPF DataGrid: How to style the "Remove Row" button

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have already styled many attributes in the WPF DataGrid, such as background, font color, etc.

However, when you delete a row from the datagrid, there appears to be a "Remove Row" button on the DataGrid. I would like to style it too, such as the background, font color, etc.

How can I do it without overriding the entire DataGrid template?
Many Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How is your context menu specified? Do you have some ContextMenu="" Attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ContextMenu.
You can add this XAMl code to your App.Xaml you can style it.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="HasDropShadow"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Background="{StaticResource MenuPopupBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" />
          </Border.BorderBrush>
          <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="Padding"
                    Value="0,3,0,3" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="CornerRadius"
                    Value="4" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Control colors.-->
<Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


<Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
<Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

<!--Border colors-->
<Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

<!--Control-specific resources.-->
<Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

<Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
  <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```